# Export Pandas Dataframe to subprocess as stdin

Tags: python, pandas, subprocess, stdout

I am using python to query an impala database and return the results of the SQL query as a dataframe. I would like to pass that dataframe as stdin to a subprocess call to another program, and cannot figure out how.

```
# create dataframe from query results
query_df = cur.execute(sql_query)

# create subprocess command
subprocess_cmd = r'''{} | java -Xmx16g -jar snpeff.jar -t GRCh37.75 > out_file}'''.format(query_df)

# run the subprocess command
ps = sp.Popen(subprocess_cmd, shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, cwd=os.getcwd())
try:
    print ps.communicate()
except sp.CalledProcessError as e:
    print e
```

I can print the pandas dataframe to stdout, as follows:

```
query_df.to_csv(sys.stdout, sep='\t')
```

But I have no idea how to feed it into subprocess, or if I'm on the right track. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: does it work if you just replace `format.(query_df)` with `format(query_df.to_csv(sep='\t'))`? If you call `to_csv` without specifiying a file, it just returns the csv as as string

Comment: @maxymoo I tried that... it didn't work :(

Comment: oh also can you try  changing `{}` to `echo -e "{}"`

Comment: That doesn't work, either. It just passes 'None' to the subprocess command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have to write query_df contents explicitly in a csv-file and after that tell the subprocess where it can get the data.

```
# write to a file
query_df.to_csv('test.csv', sep='\t')

# create subprocess command
subprocess_cmd = r'''cat test.csv | java -Xmx16g -jar snpeff.jar -t GRCh37.75 > out_file}'''.format(query_df)
```

Or do you definitely want to use stdout?

Ok, I found the decision with stdin :)

```
# create subprocess command
subprocess_cmd = r'''java -Xmx16g -jar snpeff.jar -t GRCh37.75 > out_file}'''.format(query_df)

# run the subprocess command
ps = sp.Popen(subprocess_cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, cwd=os.getcwd())
try:
  print ps.communicate(query_df.to_csv(sep='\t'))
except sp.CalledProcessError as e:
  print e
```

Please, try it.

Comment: You are my new hero, the second option worked great! We want to save time reading/writing files by streaming output directly to the snpeff program so the streaming option is great! Thanks!

Also:
import subprocess as sp

Then I would need to add sp to the pipe commands: 
stdin=sp.PIPE etc.

Comment: I was very glad to help so nice bioinformatics scientist :) If you will have any questions, please, feel free to ask me - I like python and pandas.